# ¿Cómo se llama una zona donde las mascotas pueden orinar y defecar?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, animales

Esta pregunta se me vino a la mente gracias a la pésima traducción que vi en el aeropuerto de Nueva York ("Pet Relief Area - Área de mascotas relief"), aunque no se me ocurre ninguna traducción breve correcta.  He visto «zona de alivio» pero obviamente esa frase tiene otros significados.  Debe referirse a una zona del aeropuerto donde los dueños de mascotas pueden llevar los mismos para mear y cagar.

¿Cómo se le denomina a este tipo de zona en castellano?

> Pet Relief Area - Área de mascotas relief
>
> [image: Pet Relief Area - Área de mascotas relief]

Comment: Esa gente es ridicula. Hubieran  podido traducir eso: Zona de conforto-mascotes. Creo que no existe todavia en otros lugares. No estoy segura pero encontré un artículo que describe lo que pasa en EEUU....

Comment: @Lambie Sí que existe en otros aeropuertos: [_El aeropuerto de Palma instala tres 'pipican' en sus instalaciones_](http://www.europapress.es/turismo/transportes/aeropuertos/noticia-aeropuerto-palma-instala-tres-pipican-instalaciones-20180528143001.html).

Answer (score 6):

Por donde yo vivo (Andalucía) y no sé si de forma extendida en España se usa *pipicán* (con acento en la *a*, pero escrito *pipican* o incluso "pipi-can" o "pipí-can"). Por ejemplo [en este artículo](http://sevillaciudad.sevilla.abc.es/reportajes/este-alcosa-torreblanca/sociedad-este-alcosa-torreblanca/los-parques-para-perros-que-ofrece-sevilla/) sobre áreas para perros en parques de Sevilla:

> *En este último [parque con áreas de esparcimiento canino], los animales pueden ejercitarse en dos pistas con equipamientos de agility, aunque, como conviene recordar, no son «pipi-can», por lo que el dueño deberá encargarse de los excrementos caninos.*

Fíjate que el artículo distingue pues entre una zona habilitada con juegos para perros, en las que los dueños aún tienen la obligación de recoger los excrementos, de una zona habilitada expresamente para el alivio perruno, en las que eso no es necesario (aunque recomendable según el pipicán).

Por otro lado, veo que el término no es exclusivo de mi zona. Por ejemplo, una empresa de Valencia de mobiliario urbano ofrece [varias soluciones](http://www.mobiliariosurbanos.com/es/mobiliario-urbano/pipican) de *pipican*, y de hecho así es como se llama la sección en su web. Y en Cataluña también se usa, véase este [titular de El País](https://elpais.com/ccaa/2018/05/10/catalunya/1525985434_501587.html) (que por fin lo acentúan [según la recomendación de la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1036525548670005249)):

> “¡Colau al pipicán!”
>   Varios cientos de personas y perros se manifiestan en Barcelona contra las restricciones a los canes en los parques de la ciudad.

Por último, algunas imágenes que atestiguan su uso oficial (la primera es de [Bullas](https://www.laopiniondemurcia.es/municipios/2018/04/23/mascotas-bullas-pone-marcha-primer/916097.html), provincia de Murcia):

[image: Pipicán Murcia]

[image: Pipi-can]

---

Sobre su ortografía: buscando "pipican" de forma genérica (sin las comillas) en Google aparecen 100000 resultados. Buscando con las comillas el término exacto, "pipican" ofrece 63000 resultados y "pipicán" apenas 6000, aunque yo siempre lo he oído pronunciado con acento en la *a* final, como palabra aguda.

Sobre su uso: los primeros textos que usan la palabra son de la década de los años 1990.

Comment: por aquí por el norte hace muchos años pusieron una especie de retretes para perros, una plataforma de plastico con un palo para que mearan ahí pero no funcionó, le llamaban pipicán también

Comment: @blonfu buen apunte, así confirmamos que su uso no es exclusivo de la costa mediterránea, como parecía.

Comment: Me parece muy bien, pero estos lugares se encuentran en el exterior, y no en los aeropuertos, ¿ verdad ? :) Pipicán[ino]. ¡Qué maravilla ! Mi marido dice ñorda-can (un término extremeño). [para reirse]

Comment: @Lambie en un [comentario a la pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27280/c%c3%b3mo-se-llama-una-zona-donde-las-mascotas-pueden-orinar-y-defecar/27286?noredirect=1#comment45839_27280) tienes un enlace a un artículo que habla de la instalación de tres pipicanes en el aeropuerto de Palma.

Comment: @Charlie Sí, pero no sabemos si se encuentran dentro o fuera. En todo caso, me parece muy bien. :)

Comment: @Lambie según el artículo, dos están en el exterior (solárium y aparcamiento) y una en el interior (zona de embarque).

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado "**baños para perros**" en un artículo sobre la cuestión: [*Lo último en los aeropuertos: baños exclusivos para perros*](http://www.elmundo.es/viajes/america/2018/07/20/5b50752746163faca68b4615.html).

> [...] cada vez son más también los aeropuertos que se suman a la idea de contar con un baño exclusivo para mascotas.
>
> [...] una normativa del país ,a través del departamento de Transporte, obliga a los aeropuertos con más de 10.000 pasajeros al día que instalen un aseo especial para las mascotas que viajan con sus dueños.